# Referring to task local variable in expression (activiti 5.16.3)

Tags: activiti

I have a conditional transition from userTask1 to userTask2 (they're the ids of the tasks I defined in the bpmn).

I used the following expression in the bpmn file:

```
<conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${userTask1.varA == "uTask2"}]]></conditionExpression>
```

When I mark the userTask1 as "completed", I use the following method in the Java API:

```
Map variableMap = new HashMap();
variableMap.put("varA", "1");
activitiRule.getTaskService().complete(tasks.get(0).getId(), variableMap, true);
```

Notice the "true" param at the end, this is to say that those variables are local to the task.

In a separate test I could verify that the the variable is indeed stored locally to the task.

But, in this test (with the conditional transition), I'm getting this error:

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in expression: ${userTask1.varA == "uTask2"}
at org.activiti.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression.getValue(JuelExpression.java:53)
...
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.impl.javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot resolve identifier 'userTask1'
```

How to solve this?

Thanks,
Raka

Comment: By the way..., after doing other experiments (a looping process: task1 -> task2 -> task3 -> task1 -> end).... I found out that the first task1 is not the same instance as the second task1.... Which makes me wonder: what is the point of task local variable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every execution in Activiti have variables and nested execution can see parents variables, doesn't stand for opposite direction. Problem is that you are declaring variable in local scope of the current execution so only that execution can see it. You can avoid that if you bind variable to process instance scope, process instance is nothing more than another execution but it is root/parent execution of the all others (except call activities).

Execution is like a sequence of elements planned for execution, I'll dare to compare it with threads in java but more abstract and with persisted state, execution can have nested executions. There are many elements that create new executions; parallel/inclusive gateways, boundary/immediate events, call activities, sub-processes...
I think that completion of user task also starts new execution.

You can easy check your execution in database table `act_ru_execution` and variables in table `act_ru_variable`, variables have FK on executions.

Hope it helps.